# Is it possible to move a visualization to another table?

Tags: visualisation, carto, table

Is it possible to move a visualization to another table?  e.g. when merging two tables, it creates a 3rd.   OR to completely replace a table and maintain the viz??

I don't want to lose the original table's visualization nor recreate it (i've already done it once this morning when moving between accounts).  But I've added 5 columns to integrate into the viz.

Anything? or should i just recreate it?

thanks,
chrism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible at this moment, you'll have to recreate the visualization.